# how to add Eclipse project with jni to Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface, ndk-build

I want to add my libary project with jni build works with eclipse.
but when I add this project to android studio. As module it compiles perfectly, but when I run it, it crashes with the error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mydemo/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libloader-jni.so"
```

Please help me out....

Comment: Compile jni  to .so file, and put them in jnilibs file folder.

Comment: did already, same exeption occure my friend

Comment: How did you get so file?

Comment: i have old project compile already with eclipse

Comment: Where did you put your so file?

Comment: i try libs,jniLibs both but not working

Comment: ITS WORKING FINE WITH ECLISE

Comment: Add this code into build.gradle

sourceSets {
        main {
            jni.srcDirs = ["jni"]
        }
    }

Comment: You may need to config in build.gradle.

Comment: sourceSets { main { jni.srcDirs = ['jniLibs','libs'] } }

Comment: @DilavarMalek how you resolved in eclipse?